# Iterate an array of objects containing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got values inside array objects and supposed to populate in readable format but stuck as output gets error like "[object Object] undefined".

my desired output is supposed to be like:

Saab - Smodel1,Smodel2,Smodel3,
Volvo -  Vmodel1,VmodeL2,Vmodel3,
BMW -   Bmodel1,Bmodel2,Bmodel3,

here is my code:

```
const cars = [{
  "Saab":["Smodel1", "Smodel2", "Smodel3"],
  "Volvo":["Vmodel1", "Vmodel2", "Vmodel3"],
  "BMW":["Bmodel1", "Bmodel2", "Bmodel3"]
}];
let car_model = '';

for(let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
car_model += cars[i] + "-" + cars[i][i] + "<br/>";
}
```

added for reference

```
 var cars = 
            var car, hash;
            for (var model in cars) {
                car = key;
                hash = cars[key];
                get(car, hash);
                seen(car, hash);
                (function loop(car, hash) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        get(car, hash);
                        loop(car, hash);
                    
                    }, 1000);
                })(car, hash);
            }
```

Current output:
[object Object] undefined

Comment: Is there a reason you are wrapping your object in an array?

Comment: it came from php array

Comment: There is no benefit to adding the square braces (depth) to your object.  This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329) -- rather than working around the problem, improve the input data structure.

Comment: yes definitely. im working on it. thank you

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is iterate over the keys and values of the object at once - iterate over the `Object.entries` instead of over `.length` (which doesn't exist for plain objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the only single object in your array using `Object.entries(...)` and then `Array.map(...)` the values to the desired strings. `String.join(...)` will also be of great help, as it allows you to easily join an array to a single string, with a given seperator.

```js
const cars = [{
 "Saab":["Smodel1", "Smodel2", "Smodel3"],
  "Volvo":["Vmodel1", "Vmodel2", "Vmodel3"],
  "BMW":["Bmodel1", "Bmodel2", "Bmodel3"]
}];

console.log(
  Object
    .entries(cars[0]) // take your first (and only) element and split it into key value pairs
    .map(([key, values]) => // map the key value pairs
      `${key} - ${values.join(",")}` // to the desired output format
    )
    .join(",") // join the mapped values by a ,
)
```

Comment: well good work right there sir however i will go on the "for loop" kind of thingy.

Comment: @saintthomas If you have found your answer, please accept it.

Comment: havent found it yet but im working on using jquery children() function. maybe populating it on a table with some php manipulation will do the trick. please see above post i have added some reference of my script that its a bit difficult in integrating your input

Comment: Your question has multiple answers. If you have another question, open another StackOverflow thread. This question has nothing to do with jQuery children, or anything else.

Comment: yah what i have added there is just for reference for some scenario. its just the for loop what i need thank you

Comment: You have answers for your loop. Mark one as the answer. What you are doing right now is just disrespectful to anyone that offered up their time to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cars = {
 "Saab":["Smodel1", "Smodel2", "Smodel3"],
  "Volvo":["Vmodel1", "Vmodel2", "Vmodel3"],
  "BMW":["Bmodel1", "Bmodel2", "Bmodel3"]
};

car_models = '';
for (let i=0; i < Object.keys(cars).length; i ++) {
    models = cars[Object.keys(cars)[i]];
    car_models += Object.keys(cars)[i] + " " + models.join();
}
```

Outputs

```
Saab Smodel1,Smodel2,Smodel3Volvo Vmodel1,Vmodel2,Vmodel3BMW Bmodel1,Bmodel2,Bmodel3
```

Comment: tnx for the input but there is a problem since its cars[] (array)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only traditional for-loops

```js
const cars = [{
 "Saab":["Smodel1", "Smodel2", "Smodel3"],
  "Volvo":["Vmodel1", "Vmodel2", "Vmodel3"],
  "BMW":["Bmodel1", "Bmodel2", "Bmodel3"]
}];

let car_model = '';

for(let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  const brands = Object.keys(cars[i]);
  for (let j = 0; j < brands.length; j++) {
    const models = cars[i][brands[j]];
    for (let k = 0; k < models.length; k++) {
        car_model += brands[j] + "-" + models[k] + "<br/>";
    }
  }
}

console.log(car_model)
```

Comment: well nice work but its kind of distribution list on it i prefer in a one line preference

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner using `Object.entries` and `forEach`:

```js
const cars = [{
  "Saab":["Smodel1", "Smodel2", "Smodel3"],
  "Volvo":["Vmodel1", "Vmodel2", "Vmodel3"],
  "BMW":["Bmodel1", "Bmodel2", "Bmodel3"]
  }];

Object.entries(cars[0]).forEach(([key, value]) => document.write(`${key}: ${value}`,'<br>'));
```

Comment: well thank you for the input but i will go on for loop